# Finding a slider like toyota website

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I need a slider which is used in www.toyota.com. This slider looks awesome and I am going to design a motor car showroom's website. They recommanded this slider. Can anyone help me to find this slider?

Answer (score 0):

There are many JQuery plugins which have the carousel and slider effects. I personally use [kenwheeler](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) for that. Its simple to use and supports cross browser functionality.

Comment: I know that but I need a slider same as toyota.com

Comment: The whole thing in toyota.com is slider. You can modify any of the plugin(beware of the copyrights) and add effects accordingly. For toyota.com, each slide is a div with custom script. Beware the effects won't work in IE9 and below (CSS3 fails).